# How can I do "rake db:migrate" with mongoid and active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, migrate

I want to migrate active record (mysql) database.

I use database both mongoid and active record. I typed this code.

`rails generate active_record:migration CreateUsersTable`

It worked. But I can't migrate it with active_record. How can I migrate active record like `rake active_record:db:migrate`?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, nothing happened.   

```root@localhost:~/App# rake db
root@localhost:~/App#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I missed adding `active_record/railtie` to application.rb

After I added following line, it works!

`require "active_record/railtie"`

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with mixing both AR and Mongoid in the same project.  What works best is to create a new rails app with default AR settings and then add Mongoid gem.  I had issues with initializers so I had to manually created some models.

```
class Armodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Mngmodel
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
end
```

I was able to create relationships bwn 2 different AR models and 2 different Mongoid models but not between AR model and Mongo model.  I could see this being an interesting solution in certain cases and would be curious to hear of people who actually applied it in production.